# Uncaught TypeError: lower.charAt(...).toUppererCase is not a function at capitalize Alert.jsx:6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

`

```
import React from "react";

function Alert(props) {
    const capitalize = (word) => {
    const lower = word.toLowerCase(); 
    let msg = lower.charAt(0).toUppererCase() + lower.slice(1);
    return msg;
   };
     
  return (
    props.alert && (
     <div className={`alert alert-${props.alert.type} alert-dismissible fade show`} 
       role="alert">
      <strong>{capitalize(props.alert.type)}</strong> : {props.alert.msg}
     </div>
    ));
}
export default Alert;
```

`

I was trying to capitalize the first letter of my props.alert.type. but the console throws an err!!
before writing the capitalize function the code was running just fine!!
the type is a string "success", had to capitalize "s" but now I have this error before capitalize function I was getting that alert message as I intended.
[console err msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN81g.png)

Comment: syntax error `.toUppererCase()` to `.toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 1):

Typo, change

`lower.charAt(0).toUppererCase()` to `lower.charAt(0).toUpperCase()`

Comment: Rather than answering the question, the question should really be closed by flagging the question as being caused by a typo as it's unlikely to really be helpful to anyone else.